# Pasting styled text from system clipboard

Tags: vim, copy-paste

In vim, how might a person paste styled text from the system clipboard rather than the plain-text?

For example, copying from a web browser and pasting in to a word processor typically results in styled text, including basic formatting (bold) and links, being pasted. How might a person copy from the browser in the same way but paste the original HTML representation of the text in to vim?

Comment: Paste it into a word processor and save as raw text.

Answer (score 8):

Temporary adding `html` to `clipboard` option should help:

```
set clipboard^=html
put +
set clipboard-=html
```

> ```
>   html            When the clipboard contains HTML, use this when
>                   pasting.  When putting text on the clipboard, mark it
>                   as HTML.  This works to copy rendered HTML from
>                   Firefox, paste it as raw HTML in Vim, select the HTML
>                   in Vim and paste it in a rich edit box in Firefox.
>                   You probably want to add this only temporarily,
>                   possibly use BufEnter autocommands.
>                   Only supported for GTK version 2 and later.
>                   Only available with the |+multi_byte| feature.
> ```

Comment: When doing the `put +` I get "Invalid register name".

Comment: @ElijahLynn: Read `:help quoteplus`. Possibly `put *` will work instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the ZyX's answer was supposed to do in 2012. But in 2024 `set clipboard^=html` throws an E474 error. Since this page appeared as the first google result when searching for "vim/neovim paste rich text clipboard" I'll leave my solution here.
I couldn't find any native Neovim functionality for this. So nothing has changed in this regard. But if you have `wl-clipboard` (containing `wl-copy` & `wl-paste`) or x11's / xorg's analogs (like `xclip`) installed you can bind this lua snippet as callback to `<leader>ht` or `<M-v>` for example:

```lua
local handle = io.popen("wl-paste -t text/html", "r")
# "*a" - Returns all the contents
local result = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()

if result then
  vim.api.nvim_put({result}, "", true, true)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Vim doesn't support rich text: it's a text editor, not a word processor.

Comment: Be careful with the crotchetiness; you're missing the point that, in some cases, "rich text" is, in fact, plain text that a text editor can handle perfectly well.

Comment: I don't think I'm missing any point, here. Copying **text** from a browser can't result in **text** in Vim because Vim is not a rich text editor. The best you can get is either raw `text` or `<strong>text</strong>` as per ZyX's answer. Actually I think I misunderstood the last part of your question. I thought you wanted **text** in Vim while it appears that you want `<strong>text</strong>`. Sorry about that. Go with ZyX answer, it's spot-on.

Answer (score -2):

Vim edits only plain text, more or less. In any case, what you're asking is not possible.

If you want you can look up source of the HTML page, and paste that in Vim, but that is still plain text (depends on the definition; I still view markup as plain text).